# Сортировка log файла по POSIX времени

Tags: java

Я сливаю все лог файлы формата time message\n, где time в формате POSIX в один, но они получаются неотсортированными по времени.
Например имею такой,

```
Contents of file first.log
1635940243 nice
1635940244 cool
Contents of file second.trace
1635940283 true
1635940294 cool
Contents of file third.log
1635940253 nice
1635940264 cool
```

Как можно отсортировывать файл с логами, по POSIX time

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод [`Files.write(Path path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> lines, OpenOption ... options)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-), тогда нужно объединить несколько входных потоков из разных файлов в один, затем применить сортировку, что-то вроде:

```java
Files.write(
    Paths.get("result.log"),
    Stream.of(
        Files.lines(Paths.get("first.log")),    // Stream<String> 1
        Files.lines(Paths.get("second.trace")), // Stream<String> 2
        Files.lines(Paths.get("third.log"))     // Stream<String> 3
    ) // Stream<Stream<String>>
    .flatMap(s -> s) // Stream<String> все потоки объединены
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(MyClass::getTimestamp)) // 
    .iterator() // вернуть Iterable<String>
);
```

Сортировка может быть без компаратора, если все таймстемпы имеют одинаковую длину (отработает обычная алфавитная сортировка), но в общем случае понадобится отдельный метод для извлечения таймстемпа из строки лога:

```
static long getTimestamp(String line) {
    if (null == line || line.isEmpty()) {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE; // nulls last, or 0 if nulls first
    }
    return Long.parseLong(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));
}
```